# Can I instantiate a variable but assign a value to value later?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a variable in my controller and would like to assign a value later, when click on a button. i.e.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);    

....

var userArray = [
    {name: "John", age: 25}, {name: "Jim", age: 30}
];

app.controller('Page2Controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am from page 2.';
    $scope.newArray = [];

    $scope.addUsers = function(){
        scope.newArray = userArray;

        console.log($scope.newArray);
    }  
}

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/page2', {
       templateUrl : 'pages/page2.html',
       controller  : 'Page2Controller'

   ...
```

page2.html

```
<div>
     <p>{{ message }}</p>

     <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="user in Page2Controller.newArray">{{user.name}}</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div id="sideMenu">
        <h2>Campaign</h2>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

I don't understand why the $scope.user is displayed in console but in html page the "ng-repeat" doesn't display the users. May it be that ng-repeat cannot display data that was added dynamically?

Can someone help me? Appreciate that.

Comment: You have this : `scope.newArray = userArray;` and I think it would be better to add the `$` sign `$scope.newArray = userArray;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never called that function I guess..

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);    
var userArray = [{name: "John", age: 25}, {name: "Jim", age: 30}];
app.controller('Page2Controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am from page 2.';
    // $scope.newArray = [];
    $scope.addUsers = function(){
        $scope.newArray = userArray;
        console.log($scope.newArray);
    }  
    $scope.addUsers();
});
```

and html

```
<div ng-controller="Page2Controller">
                         <p>{{ message }}</p>

                         <ul>
                             <li ng-repeat="user in newArray">{{user.name}}</li>
                         </ul>
                    </div>
```

I have statically used your controller as i didn't implement the ngRoute.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It hinted to the right answer. Instead of ng-repeat="user in Page2Controller.newArray" I did  ng-repeat="user in newArray"  and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in scope.newArray">{{user.name}}</li>
```

I don't think 'Page2Controller' is known in the template context.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have need a ng-click derective where you have to click such as

```
<button type="button" ng-click="asigningValue()"></button>
```

Then in your Controller you have to assign what you want such as in controller
After that you have need to bind you assign value in the directive such as

```
app.controller('Page2Controller', function($scope) {
$scope.asigningValue=function(){
     $scope.message = 'Look! I am from page 2.';
  } 
}
```

Then show using directive using data binding as

```
<p ng-bind-html="message"></p>
```

Hope it will be helpful!

Thank you!